# Can't process JSONs in different folders

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have the following structure:

```
/folder_1
    file_1.json
        json_1
        json_2
    file_2.json
        json_1
        ...
/folder_2
    file_1.json
        json_1
    file_2.json
        json_1
    file_3.json
        json_1
        json_2
...
```

I have tried multiple ways to read these files a create a DataFrame where every row is a row from the JSONs. Also, the JSONs aren't flat, so they are like this:

```
 {
     "a": "1",
     "b": {
        "b_1": "val",
        "b_2": []
        ...
      },
      ...
 }
```

I have tried the following:

[image: For loop]

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/path/to/folders"):
    for json_f in filenames:
        print (json_f)
        json_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, json_f)
        training_df = json_normalize(pd.Series(open(json_file_path). 
                                     readlines()).apply(json.loads))

print (training_df.count())
training_df.to_csv('training_data.csv')
```

In a scenario where I have 5 folders with 11 .json inside and around 19 jsons inside the .json files, the program is able to read the 11 files but the CSV generated only has 2 rows instead of 19.

Comment: What does it mean to have "19 jsons inside the .json files"? You can't have "multiple JSONs in a .json". I mean you can have whatever you want in there since it's just a text file but it seems you have invalid JSON files. Please give an example of what "multiple JSONs inside a .json" looks like for you.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderReynolds, thanks for your reply! What I mean with this is that every line of my .json file is a new json:

     {"a": "1", "b": "2"...}
     {"a": "2", "b": "5"...}

Comment: Okay, so that's not actually a valid JSON file. It is a [JSON lines](http://jsonlines.org/) text file (standard is to use `.jsonl` extension). BUT, your program actually works anyways since you're doing a `json.loads()` on each line of the file. However, the problem is you're overwriting the `training_df` on each loop. You need to concatenate these dataframes. The easiest thing to do is to create an empty list, and append the dataframes to them. Then once the loop is over, create your final dataframe with `df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)`. And push *that* out to a CSV.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work, lot of thanks @AlexanderReynolds!